# Wine 5.0.2 desktop launcher for programs

Tags: 20.04, wine, launcher

I installed wine ver 5.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. In addition to that I installed Notepad++.

The command:

```
wine /home/user/.wine/drive_c/'Program Files (x86)'/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

starts Notepad++ correctly.

I tried to create a NotepadPlusPlus.desktop file in the desktop folder. This file is executable (rwxr-xr-x)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=NotepadPlusPlus
Icon=/home/user/pictures/NotepadPlusPlus.png
Exec=wine "/home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
Type=Application
Categories=wine;
```

Clicking this icon does not start the application though. What is wrong with the Exec command?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your setup and it also didn't work for me at first. I got it to work by replacing 'wine' with `/usr/bin/wine` in the `Exec=` line. It worked for me after the change.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: actually there is a Notepad++.desktop file in the home directory after the Notepad++ installation via wine.

```
~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Notepad++.desktop
```

This file needs to be copied into the Desktop folder and made executable. Then right click the icon on the desktop and select allow launch.

The content of the Notepad++.desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Notepad++
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/user/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/user/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Notepad++.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/user/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++
Icon=1DE5_notepad++.0
StartupWMClass=notepad++.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to use what's in my opinion is a much simpler form for the desktop file. Here is an example for a made up application called Examp:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Examp
GenericName=Application description
Exec=wine /home/user/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program\\ Files\\ (x86)/Examp/Examp.exe
Icon=/home/user/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/Examp/Examp.ico
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Examp.exe
```

The trick is to make sure that in the path that follows the wine command all spaces are preceded with two backslashes ("\\")

Hope this is helpful